# Providing Enterprise License Server Management?

Tags: arcgis-license-manager

I was hoping to get some information from others who have deployed an enterprise GIS License Manager for ArcGIS 10.x software.  Honestly, I would like to see if our current setup is adequate or if we should venture into a new setup architecture.

Currently, we have multiple departments who each purchase their own licenses.  To ensure departments only have access to their purchased licenses, ArcGIS License Managers have been installed for each department and their licenses authorized on each LM respectively.  Some of these LM's are on their own dedicated virtual server, and some are installed on client machines in the department (not ideal and we plan to change this immediately).  Our idea to both keep the licenses separated, and also not use any of our farm resources is to place physical boxes (ones that have been replaced via PC upgrades, etc.) in each department, install LM on the box and authorize the licenses.  Each department would have it's own box, and we can administer these via remove access.

Here are questions I have:

1. Is it at all possible to run multiple instances of LM on one machine, and just change the outgoing port so each instance has it's own dedicated I/O access? (i.e. Dept A uses 27000, Dept B uses 27001, etc.)
2. I have heard (and read somewhere), that individual licenses on LM's can be managed down to the user level via changing the LM configuration file.  If this is so, have any of you implemented this setup and how successful has it proved to be?

Again, we are just wanting to ensure we are implementing a practical architecture.  We've used the above setup for years so I believe it's time we revisit this and see if better practices exist.

Here are some of the posts/articles we have looked over for ideas so far:

- [Managing ArcGIS floating licenses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/managing-arcgis-floating-licenses)
- [hardcoding port number is ArcGIS License Manager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15385/hardcoding-port-number-in-arcgis-license-manager)

Comment: Question 1. yes we run multiple licenses (AutoCAD,ArcGIS,FME) from a virtual server(s) ports can be assigned for DeptA, DeptB

Comment: Flexera is the underlying software that manages the licenses see http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/entitlement-management/flexnet-licensing/tab/resources

Comment: Just so I understand everything, using a product such as FlexNET, Dept A's ArcGIS concurrent licenses can be hosted on port 27000, and Dept B's ArcGIS concurrent licenses can be hosted on port 27001, and so on... Correct?

Comment: two separate licenses can be on different ports, if the licenses are merged then they would be on available on one port only.

Comment: It potentially sounds like a headache trying to configure our setup using this scenario.  Departments have multiple concurrent licenses, and it would be important to restrict departments to only their pool of concurrent licenses.  You mention "merging licenses" - I've never heard of doing this.  If I could merge each departments licenses together, then using one port per department may be possible.  Related question - using the FlexNET product, when setting the license manager in ArcGIS Administrator, do you simply add the port number, i.e. licenseserver:27000 ?

Comment: depends on the lmgrd.exe tool for each application

Comment: The only application we would be using this for is ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: see http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/lhc++/FLEXLM/htmlman/flexuser/chap2.htm