# ArcGIS Administrator Licenses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-license-manager, license

How can I find number of Licences in ArcGIS Administrator from arcobjects or any files?

[image]

Comment: Not sure but you can try either through ArcPy(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000000z000000) or ArcObject(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000066000000)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I tried finding our license numbers today in ArcGIS Admin and gave up and called ESRI. They said the only way I could see license numbers is going to the [My ESRI](https://my.esri.com/welcome) website logging in to the account who purchased the licenses.  From there navigate to products and there should be a report system to filter your license numbers.  Be advised the ESRI support person said that you are not able to see which computer has which license. Here are the more specific directions from ESRI.

```
===========
Using My Esri
===========
1) Open any internet browser, and in the address bar key in "my.esri.com"
2) Log into My Esri using your Esri global account
3) Once you are logged in, select "My Organizations"
4) Further select, "Products"
5) Under the "Products" tab, you will see "Downloads" and "Authorizations"
6) Selecting "Downloads" allows you to view and download Esri Products
7) Selecting "Authorizations" allows you to view the Authorization Number for the products you have purchased.
```

Answer (score 1):

One method, not pretty but works, is to parse the output of the command line `lmutil lmstat -a -c @my_lic_server`. There's a lot of noise, but the lines you want resemble:

```
Users of ARC/INFO:  (Total of 6 licenses issued;  Total of 2 licenses in use)
```

lmutil can be found under `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\LicenseManager\License10.x\bin`.

Also see [Managing ArcGIS floating licenses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/managing-arcgis-floating-licenses/133282#133282) for an example of how we use it from a shared location.